# Move user profiles from one server to another (without permission)

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there anyway to move/replicate folders that you don't have permissions for, without touching the security permissions?

In particular i'm trying to copy the "users" folder from one windows server (DC) to another. When a user is created the user itself is owner of its folder and policy demands that administrators can't access these.

Last time i did this i just used DFS to replicate the folders over, which works, but it's a bit messy.

How do you guys manage user migration?

Comment: Use [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and run it as [System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528/how-do-you-run-cmd-exe-under-the-local-system-account), using [Syinternals psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).

Comment: Tried PsExec `PsExec -i -s -d CMD` and then `robocopy "x\dir" "y\dir" /copyall /S /E /R:0 /W:30 /DCOPY:T > C:\log.txt` but it didn't work. It seems not even system can touch user folders.

Comment: What's the result of whoami in cmd.exe - `nt authority\system`? Can you enter the user folders with `cd c:\users\...`?

Comment: Yes, `nt authority\system ID: S-1-5-18` and yes i can enter the users folders (which i can't in a normal administrator run CMD window). but still get "Access is denied." when i try to robocopy the userfolders... strange

Comment: I managed to move a test user the folder while still maintaining security settings for it. However, that changed the security settings for above folders to allow the moved member to browse all files over the folder that was moved... I'll just use dfs replication. Seems to be alot easier.

Answer (score 2):

When I last had to accomplish something similar, I used [XCACLS](http://ss64.com/nt/xcalcs.html) to modify the current permissions on the folder (`/e` edits instead of replaced ACL) to give you full control.  You can then move the folder and then remove your own permissions.

Alternatively, you can use the get-acl and set-acl cmdlets in powershell to get a permission set: `$oldPermissions = get-acl "C:\users\folder"`, edit the permissions to move and then use set-acl to reapply the old permissions to the folder at the new location

Both of these, however do involve editing permissions.

Other options include:

- Robocopy As Admin
- DFS replication
- Offline (Linux LiveCD) file copies - my preference being backtrack/kali
- Backup & restore (Backupexec, Windows Server Backup etc)

If you really are in a Jam, you can just create the new folder structure, point the users at it and then give them a link (mapped drive, UNC in an email etc) to the old box to grab a copy of any data they need/want on the understanding that you're killing the old server in x weeks time.